# Не отображается состояние Indeterminate на панели задач в Windows7

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-7

Простое воспроизведение проблемы. Создаем окно, указываем:

```
  <Window.TaskbarItemInfo>
    <TaskbarItemInfo ProgressState="Indeterminate"/>
  </Window.TaskbarItemInfo>
```

Запускаем в Windows7 - на панели ничего не отображается.

Запускаем в Windows10 - на панели ожидаемый бегающий статус-бар.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Внезапно и неожиданно - помогло выключение и включение настройки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]